# How to fetch users in particular domain programmatically in Sitecore9

Tags: security, sitecore-api

We recently upgraded our project to Sitecore9 initial release from 7.2. We were re-compiling our code including latest Sitecore.Kernel. We got this error:

> error CS0117: 'Factory' does not contain a definition for 'GetDomain'

for below code:

```
var domain = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDomain("extranet");
var allUsers = domain.getUsers();
```

There is no `GetDomain` function in `Configuration.Factory`. I think it got replaced by `GetDomainMap`. But that doesn't have `getUsers()` function. Can someone help us how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
var domain = Sitecore.SecurityModel.DomainManager.GetDomain("extranet");
domain.GetUsers()
```

Comment: In that case, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: By the Way, Is there any link which have new api's and their methods? or any trick to resolve such errors. Basically I have to resolve the way api handling in 9 version.

Comment: I'm not aware of any link or resources.. We are creating that documentation here :)